# How can I add drivers for custom properties?

Tags: scripting, properties, drivers

Suppose that `obj` is a object. If I want to add a driver for its scale X, I can do

```
d = obj.driver_add("scale", 0).driver
```

but if `obj` has the custom property `var`, the following

```
d = obj.driver_add("var").driver
```

gives an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct.driver_add(): property "var" not found
```

How do I add a driver in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datapath for a custom property is '["propname"]'

```
obj["prop"] = 34
obj.driver_add('["prop"]')
```

Comment: Wow you posted your answer almost at the same time when I posted mine

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
d = obj.driver_add("[\"var\"]").driver
```